# sql statement works manually but not in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

The following statement

```
        String sql="select count(*) as n1,tw.id_tweet as n2 from tweet tw inner join tweet replica on tw.id_tweet=replica.in_reply_to_status_id_str where LOWER(replica.parola_chiave)=lower( ? ) group by tw.id_tweet,tw.parola_chiave";

        PreparedStatement stmt =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1,parola_chiave_in_esame);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
         System.out.println("asd"+rs.getInt("n1"));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
```

works manually but in Java returns me an empty set. If I remove Where condition it works (obviously results aren't what i want).. why?

Comment: My guess is, your input value (parola_.....) might be wrong (or) empty.

Comment: no, it contains the right value..already checked :)

Comment: just tried..nothing :(

Comment: How does the statement look when you run it manually? Obviously it doesn't have a `?` in it, so what are you substituting for the `?`?

Comment: select tw.text as n1,tw.id_tweet as n2 from tweet tw inner join tweet replica on tw.id_tweet=replica.in_reply_to_status_id_str where LOWER(tw.parola_chiave) = lower( 'Melo' )

I have tried also to insert it directly in the string but without results

Comment: So, you have tried: `stmt.setString(1,"Melo");`

Comment: Try LOWER(tw.parola_chiave) =  "melo" without the lower

Comment: with double quotes, "Melo"

Comment: @RenéWinkler already tried :(

Comment: @GriffeyDog with single quotes gives me a compile error

Comment: Well, are you sure your Java connection is the same as whatever you connect as when you run it manually?

Comment: Have you alread tried to debug it?

Comment: Do you call rs.next() ?

Comment: @volperossa I fixed the quotes in my comment.

Comment: @GriffeyDog yes....if it was a different connection, I expected no results also without where clause

Comment: @RenéWinkler yes, I call rs.next() in a while loop and it doesn't go inside the loop

Comment: can you post the other part of your code?

Comment: @RenéWinkler I updated the code in the question

Comment: try removing `?` and concatinating the string

Comment: @singhakash done, without results

Comment: Try a simple query (in your Java code) that just has `replica.parola_chiave` in the `select` list, with no `where` clause, to see what the database is returning to you.

Comment: print the query in console and copy it and run it to your db gui

Comment: @singhakash already done, and in my gui it works

Comment: ok i simply restart oracle service and now it works! thank you to all :)

Comment: if you think could not be useful ok... could not anyone doesn't think simply restart db? :)

Comment: Sounds like you had an uncommitted change in your GUI then. Not sure the question is going to be useful for anyone else though.